# Migración Cognito con Password

Tags: aws, cognito, migracion

Estoy tratando de realizar una migración de usuarios de un antiguo repo/servicio a Cognito en una sola ejecución. Dispongo de un fichero con los datos que requiero para crearlos incluyendo su password.
Ya no se dispone de acceso a la comprobación del antiguo servicio por lo que la migración "One-at-a-time" no podría hacerse.
Mu gustaría hacer la migración de manera que fuera transparente para el cliente, sin que este tenga que verificar nada y pueda acceder sin problemas.

Resumen:
1º Migración de una sola vez a Cognito
2º Migración incluyendo password (cosa que no ofrece Cognito)

¿Alguien sabría alguna solución (work around) para este problema?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Cognito usa una base de usuarios propia, por lo que no es posible vincular Cognito a una base personalizada como lo hacen otros IdP, esto por motivos de seguridad. Sin embargo, hay dos formas de hacer la migración que requieres:

- Crear un script que haga la migración de toda tu base de usuarios (sólo si es posible obtener la contraseña del usuario en texto plano - PROBLEMA GRAVÍSIMO DE SEGURIDAD).
- Crear un script que importe los usuarios en el logueo (opción recomendada por AWS y denominada *One-at-a-time user migration*).

La idea de la segunda opción es que el usuario al intentar ingresar a tu aplicación, el sistema intente el log-in con Cognito, si el log-in falla lo intentará con tu sistema de usuarios antiguo, si este también falla retornará el error de log-in, pero si este último pasa sin problemas debes ejecutar un script (Lambda) que cree el usuario en Cognito y almacenar su información incluyendo la contraseña que ingresó el usuario, así la siguiente vez que haga log-in el intento con Cognito pasará correctamente.

Es un tema amplio para ponerlo acá, te sugiero que le eches un ojo a la documentación de AWS donde abordan este tema con mayor detalle e incluso te dan el código y la lógica de aplicación, cuando tengas dudas o te estanques en algún punto vuelves por acá.

https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/mobile/migrating-users-to-amazon-cognito-user-pools/